# Calculated column based on what's in field of another column in same row

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a calculated column based on what's in a multple-choice column? For example, something like the pseudocode below:

```
If [column 1] is in ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"] then "category 1" else if [column 1] is in ["item 3", "item 4"] then "category 2"
```

I've looked at using something similar to `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("v",[Column1])), "OK", "Not OK")` but that doesn't quite get me there.

Comment: There is no **in** function, but we can use FIND() or SEARCH() as a workaround. What's your exact requirement?

Comment: I've added a bit more to the psuedo code, which describes the req - the column to pull from is a choice column

Answer (score 0):

If all you columns are single text column, then `FIND()` or `SEARCH()` shall be enough. It may not work for some circumstances. So Would you like to share us more information about these columns, what type are they?

If you are using SharePoint Online, I often suggest using Power Automate(Flow) to set the column value as it is more flexible and easy to set & use.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements described in your pseudo code can be accomplished using **OR** statement as shown below:

```
=IF(OR([column 1]="item 1",[column 1]="item 2",[column 1]="item 3"),"category 1",IF(OR([column 1]="item 4",[column 1]="item 5"),"category 2","category 3"))
```

[image]